# Where do I place the deployment files for asp net core application

Tags: deployment, .net-core, amazon-linux-2

I have a self contained asp net core web application and I dont know where in the file system I need to place the files. I will be using the Kestrel web server without a reverse proxy as it will be behind the AWS application load balancer. I will use amazon linux2 AMI

Answer (score 0):

It is OK to place it anywhere as long as the hosting user has sufficient permissions to the folder. Simply create a systemd service configuration and it would work properly.
Consider placing it in `/usr/share` as where the applications commonly are.